# Error while capturing video for a pre-defined time period

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

This program captures video until I press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. But I need to modify this program and capture video for 30s.

After recording the video it plays very fast and the video length reduces. I tried to add `waitKey` at the end, but it still doesn't work. After recording the video length should be the same. How can I do that? Any suggestions?

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace cv;
VideoCapture cap(0); 

    while(!(cap.isOpened() && cap.grab()))  
    {
cout << "Camera not ready" << endl;
    }
VideoWriter Writer("D:/MyVideo.avi", CV_FOURCC('P','I','M','1'),20,Size(640,480), true); 


    while (waitKey(30)!= 27)
            {
                Mat frame;
                cap >> frame; 
                Writer.write(frame); 
                imshow("D:/MyVideo", frame); 
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int64 t0 = cv::getTickCount();
while (waitKey(30)!= 27)
{
    Mat frame;
    cap >> frame; // read a new frame from video
    Writer.write(frame); //writer the frame into the file
    double t = (cv::getTickCount() - t0) / cv::getTickFrequency();
    if (t > 30)
        break;
    ...
    // now, we need to adjust to the desired framerate of 20fps, 
    // so we need to sleep for 1000/20 = 50 milliseconds
    // either have a window, and use waitKey():
    //   imshow("lalala", frame);
    //   waitKey(50);
    // or just sleep(), unfortunately system dependant ;(
    // win:
    //   Sleep(50);
    // linux, etc.:
    //   usleep(50);
}
```

Comment: program run 30s but when playing the recorded video its very fast and only 10s. can u help me to correct that too?

Comment: sorry it doesn't work. it gives me 21s length video now. before its 10s.

Comment: captured video runs faster than real time.